# Google cloud storage - java sdk - List ALL content of a folder (incl. subfolders) and distinguish files from folders

Tags: java, google-cloud-storage

**My Code**:

```
Page<Blob> blobs = storage.list(bucketName, BlobListOption.prefix(folderPath));
    for (Blob blob : blobs.iterateAll()) {
        if (!blob.isDirectory()) {
            // do stuff with the blob
        }
    }
```

It **does** list the entire content for `this` folder and it's sub-folders, including:

- files
- folders (blob objects with name ending in `/` and size `0`).

**The problem**: `blob.isDirectory()` always returns `false`.

What is the correct way to do such a listing **and** distinguish files from folders ?

Thank you.

Comment: I have posted an answer. Can you check if that helps?

Answer (score 2):

As explained in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/folders#overview)-

> Cloud Storage operates with a flat namespace, which means that folders don't actually exist within Cloud Storage. If you create an object named folder1/file.txt in the bucket your-bucket, the path to the object is your-bucket/folder1/file.txt, but there is no folder named folder1; instead, the string folder1 is part of the object's name.

So the directory you are talking about are actually not directories or folders, it is just a visual representation of folders that resembles a local file browser. That is the reason `blob.isDirectory()` always returns `false`.

Now in your case to distinguish between the files and the folders(which are not really folders but just a visual representation), you may consider using some regular expression on the blob name. As the files will not have the `/` character you can easily distinguish between the two.